# Is it possible to pin distinct Bones of a Model to a Plane while posing?

Tags: animation, rigging, constraints

I need several poses and would like to know if whether it would be possible to pin the feet or hands of a model to a plane (as floor or wall) while animating excercises like squat or push-up ?

If IK would be the answer: Setting an inverse kinematic constraint usually allows me to move the legs by moving a foot, but I want it the other way around. I used rigify and I'm still intimidated by the complexity of this rig, how should I setup the IK chain (without breaking it) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A meta-rig created by [Rigify](http://blog.digitaltutors.com/rigging-minutes-blenders-rigify-addon/) is set to forward kinematics by default. With the settings shown in the n-panel on rig-foot.ik.L/R it possible to move the body with the foot on floor by only moving the rig torso (shown in 2nd img).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Naturally, that is how inverse kinematics works. Blender also has an *auto ik* feature, look for it in the N panel when in pose mode. You can use this to quickly pose models without the need for any constraint setups. I would also recommend that you try creating your own rigs in the future, it is a very rewarding process, even more so if you make it [switchable..](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13/armature-fk-ik-toggles)

Comment: @iKlsR Thanks for your response again, I really had a hard time to understand the rig so far. I will probably come up with more questions. I've done my one rig first but it was painful to keyframe without widgets (don't know how drivers for bones are called) rigify introduces another quality of complexity and I haven't found a decent documentation. Do you have a link?

Comment: I really wouldn't recommend rigify to a beginner, it is a very complicated rig. However, [cgtuts's blender category](http://cg.tutsplus.com/category/tutorials/blender/) be of some help to you.

Comment: @iKlsR Ouch I totally missed the point, after watching this one (although for maya) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pGuR4xyi7MQ I understood the diffference between IK/FK. Thanks for the link I already watched some of them.