# Blender object Rigify - eyes, nose and fingers not moving

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, rigify

I am creating men/woman character using MakeHuman tool and import into the blender tool. I am new to the blender and MakeHuman. So I followed the steps given in the below youtube video tutorial to work with blender.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cGvalWG8HBU

After creating Armature -> Human(Meta-Rig) I Match the bones into the character. In Edit mode I pressed "G" to move the character. But other parts are moving in that character except the eyes, nose and fingers. What may be the problem. Can anyone fix me to solve this or can you give me the steps by step process to do the walk cycle a men/woman character?

Comment: You might be interested in http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1530/what-are-the-not-so-obvious-features-of-rigify

Comment: Welcome to the Blender Stack Exchange site, @karthi! Unfortunately, your question is hard to understand or unclear. Please specify details on the steps that you followed.

Comment: The video is not related to MakeHuman, I could answer this for MakeHuman MHX rigs. You probably linked the wrong video. If you import from MakeHuman your character is already fully rigged (depending on export options used).