# Parts of model do not follow during animation?

Tags: animation, rigging, bones

I am new to Blender and struggling with numerous questions. I am in the process of animating a model and all went fine with respect to "Rigging, Skinning" Now I'm attempting to "Pose" and as I move the model parts of a hat and hair don't follow.

Could this be due to "Weighting Issues"? I did manually "Weight" the areas in discussion due to the fact that I believed loose parts such as hair needed to be manipulated to the head etc. Any Ideas? I have yet to complete the first key frame an things aren't following correctly?

Comment: Could you add some screenshots of your model and weights? It's a bit hard to point out the issue here.

Comment: Hi! This is a very common issue, but it can be caused by several different things. If you can upload your blend file we can see how your scene is set up and find the cause. If you need a place to upload to, you can use [PasteAll.org](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/) -- it's very easy to use: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Also, see if the [answer to this question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8227/some-vertices-dont-move-along-with-the-rig/8228#8228) solves your problem, since I think it is exactly the same problem. I've encountered it many times myself when rigging so I wrote this answer to help people with just this problem. :)

Comment: Thorn Blair lll,

Comment: Thorn Blair lll   Thanks so much for your response and I did post the blend file at <http://www.pasteall.org/blend/28829>? and I would provide any help would be greatly appreciated! Oddly, only fragments of the hair and the models hat streak behind the model as I move it across the screen. I have figured out that the facial distortion was from using to much control in the FK's and IK's  does that sound correct what other causes promote distortion?

Comment: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/28829

Comment: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/28829%3E

Comment: Thorn Blair lll  I have managed to work out the streaking of hair, hat parts through applying more weight paint and it did work great! One other problem I have encountered is the fk's an ik's aren't working well together? I have tried using just the ik's or fk's for limb movement and the control simply pass through the limbs unless I apply the gauge control to a higher level which allows the limb movement. However, when I utilize enough flow in the gauge to promote limb movment the mesh of the models vertexs flatens and looses a smooth appearance!

Comment: After applying several scenarios I have yet to acquire an acceptable medium? is there a trick I am missing?

Comment: OMG! I'm sorry! For some reason I never saw your messages here to me, otherwise I would have replied here. Sorry about that! :)