# Animation keys on IK target instead of underlying skeleton

Tags: animation

I have animated a skeleton (that uses circles as the IK targets for the bones) and mesh with a walk cycle using the automatic keyframe insertion. However, the keys are ending up on the circles instead of the underlying skeleton. Is there anyway to animate the underlying bones using the targets?

edit: [files](http://web.ics.purdue.edu/~jmacnak/dl/journey.zip)

Comment: A lot of rigs have both IK and FK controls and have a way to switch between which one is in control. Often this is a slider located in a panel on the right of the 3DView (press N). [This question may help](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/9062/935). If not it might be hard to give an answer without seeing the rig you are using. Can you share the file? You could use [pasteall](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/).

Comment: Thanks for the response, sambler! Added my files to original post. I'm not having problems controling the skeleton, it's just that the animation keys are only appearing on the control objects. So when I export to .dae, I am only getting TranScalRot for the control objects. I actually want the TranScalRot for each bone so I can do skinning in code I am writing.

Comment: I think this is what I was looking for: [link](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?308277-bake-ik-to-fk)