# Why does part of my figure not move with my rig?

Tags: armature, rigging, bones

I created a model and then tried to add armature. But when I'm moving the rig, some of it (the mouth) stays in the place and I don't know why. Anyone know why it could happen and how to fix it?

These pictures illustrate the problem (don't mind the eye):

Rest pose:

[image]

When rotating a bone:

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: See if [this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8227/some-vertices-dont-move-along-with-the-rig/8228#8228) answers your question. If not, leave a comment and we can help you further. :)

Comment: Did that answer solve your problem?

Comment: Make sure that the mouth vertices are part of the vertex group for that particular bone. Also, make sure that those vertices have non-zero weights for that bone.