# Mesh hair goes through body

Tags: mesh

I was playing around with some MMD models I downloaded and I found that whenever I tried to pose them, its hair would go through the face.
What should I do to prevent this form happening?

[image]

Comment: It's possible the hair is not moving along with the rest of the model when you move it. If this is the case, then see [this answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8227/some-vertices-dont-move-along-with-the-rig/8228#8228) and see if it helps. If not, please leave a comment and we'll see if we can help you more. :)