# Animating my character's leg brings part of the other foot with it

Tags: animation, rigify

Once again, I'm running into problems following basic tutorials.  I tried to animate my model that I rigged with rigify, and when I move one foot, part of the other foot comes with it in some strange ways.

[image]

What's the best way to fix this?  My Blender project can be found [here](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/30254).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Some vertices don't move along with the rig](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8227/some-vertices-dont-move-along-with-the-rig)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by the fact that your foot is not correctly **weight painted**:
[image]

The red bits will follow the bone, and the blue bits won't. to fix your problem, it should look like this:
[image]

To perform the fix, select the foots vertex group, enter wait paint mode, then paint the parts of the foot you want to follow the bone red.

[image]

Comment: [Weight painting did not appear to solve my problem.](http://i.imgur.com/bHV4pie.png)