# Model doesn't follow its armature in pose mode

Tags: animation, rigging, armature

I have linked between model and bone with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (With Automatic Weights), but when I move the foot bone 'Leg Control.L' (shown with yellow circle) the model's leg doesn't completely follow the bone (shown with red circle). Also, the right leg follows the left leg but that shouldn't be followed (shown with green circle).

So how I fix this? I have tried to remake the bones but the result is same.

[image]

Comment: you'll get more info on weight painting here : http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/8228/11431

Comment: actually this issue is simple, seems between foot and the body are separated object, so i removed the foot then I created the foot again with extrude from the leg then I mirror it.