# armature deforms body

Tags: rigging, armature

I'm very new to Blender and I made a guy made out of blocks for a Game I'm working on in Unity. I made the armature and made it Parent with automated weights, now my Problem: When I for example move my right arm, it deforms the right side of my torso like it's glued to the arm, I dont know what to do please help. [image]

Comment: Almost certainly a weight painting problem. see: [Some vertices don't move along with the rig](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/8227/2217)

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the weights of the side torso.  Select the mesh, hit `Ctrl+Tab` and get into Weight painting mode.  For more information about weight-painting, please see:https://www.blender.org/manual/painting_sculpting/painting/weight_paint/introduction.html#weight-paint-in-a-nutshell

Comment: I just made it all red for test and it is still the exact same result, is that normal? https://www.dropbox.com/s/ytrnmh72r8caf9e/Model_for_everything.blend?dl=0 here is my blender file

Comment: Yep, checked the file -- you need to Weight Paint the Torso so that all the vertex group is weighted to your torso bones.

Answer (score 0):

There are only two reasons that a vertex doesn't follow the bone as you expect it to.

- It is not weighted to that bone
- It is *also* weighted to *another* bone.

Not only do you need to make sure that the vertices for your torso are assigned to your torso bone, but you *also* need to make sure that those vertices are *not* assigned to any *other* bones.