# When moving character vertex stretches (After weighting)

Tags: mesh

I am new with Blender and I just finished doing my mesh and weighting it, it is for a project I have to submit by the end of the week and still have one more character left to create and I really don't know what's that and how to fix it. So everything looks normal, but after I created a root bone and moved the object away, two vertices stretch and don't move from their place. I really really hope there's a way to fix that without having to start over :( Please let me know asap if you have any idea. Thank you!

And if you know how to fix it, please give me detailed instructions, cause this is my first project on Blender. Please! Thanks!

[image]

**Also**, does any of you know what exactly should I rotate in order to get this leg in pose mode (and all other modes) in the right position? In Edit mode it looks okay.. but only there..

[image]

Comment: seems like weight painting problem , see this http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/8228/2816

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try moving your character into that second position, where you can see which vertices are being left behind.  Then:

1. Select the mesh.  Get into Edit Mode.
2. Select the vertex (make sure Armature deform is enabled to be seen in Viewport)
   [image]
3. Hit `N` in the Viewport, and scroll down to the `Vertex Properties` and make sure `Deform` is selected.

[image]

From there, look for the bone (probably the name of a Forearm bone) that should be influencing that vertex, but isn't, and set the weight to 1.  Make sure to hit `Normalize` when your done.

Comment: Thank you so much! I think that fixed it! May I maybe ask one more question? One of the legs it deformed, I tried rotating only this bone and also this one and the one below, so either i am doing sth wrong, or just rotating in the wrong place..
I will update the first post with another image

Comment: Glad it helped Ani.  The above method works if its just a few vertices here and there that aren't behaving.  If you're having a bunch of vertices not behaving as expected, I strongly suggest jumping into weight-painting mode.  My personal tip: always paint with 'Add' mode, and always normalize when done.  'Subtract' mode is the devil in weight painting.

Comment: Ok, regarding the leg: try zeroing out the rotations in pose mode.  You may have also have weights that aren't normalize, try selecting the bones and then normalize.  Beyond that, I would post a .blend to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and link to it in a separate question.

Comment: @Ani this is not a forum or a personal support website, but a question and answer one. (see the [help] section to understand how this site works).If you have further issues please [ask a new question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). Only one question per post please.

Comment: @cegaton I understand that, but believe me, If it wasn't urgent, I wouldn't be asking about it. I hate posting questions like that and If I have enough time to research and try stuff, posting anything in Q&A websites like Stack, is the last thing I would do.. after I tried everything and really have no idea what's going on. Thanks for the tip, no worries, no more different questions here.