# Rig with joined objects

Tags: modeling, rigging, weight-painting

I have followed some tutorials and created a nice cartoon looking shoe. That shoe has three different objects(shoe itself, shoelaces and lace holes). I joined them together and everything was fine until i wanted to test rigging. when i added some bones for testing those laces and holes doesn't deform with the shoe. what might be the problem?

Without Rig:

[image: Shoe without rig]

With Rig:

[image: rig problem]

Comment: You didn't weight paint the newly joined parts of your mesh. Also see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8227/some-vertices-dont-move-along-with-the-rig/8228#8228

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos thanks for the setting me on the right direction.I will check them and update with results

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos i checked weight paints and it was ok but turns out i had to set vertices those to bones as pointed out in the first comment as you said. it helped me to figure out thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

The problem are weights. each part of the mesh gets weights automatically by assigning the armature modifier, but these don't work with intersecting objects like yours. It's almost impossible to assign proper weight to cloth details like this manually.
To solve it, try to use Mesh Deform modifier:

1. make a very simple mesh around your model.
2. add Mesh Deform to your original model, bind it with your mesh.
3. add bones to your simple mesh.