# Holes in the character

Tags: modeling

I have a problem with a character: when he is in A-pose everything is fine, but when I apply an animation it shows some holes under the arms (see the attachment). How to solve that?

Many thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Some vertices don't move along with the rig](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8227/some-vertices-dont-move-along-with-the-rig)

Comment: So what do you suggest to do? First to merge vertices and then to rig? How to merge vertices correctly?