# Parenting with automatic weights fails with an error?

Tags: animation, rigging, armature

I've worked on this character mesh and when I parent the rig to the mesh, I get a "bone heat weighting" error and nothing happens. Can anyone fix this?
Here is the link to the [.blend file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/57591352/Zoey3.blend).

Here is a picture, just to let you know what the setup looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the model's hair which leads to the error it isn't symmetrical.

If you separate the hair from the rest of the model it works fine:

In *Edit Mode*

- Select one of the hair's faces
- <kbd>P</kbd> shows the separate popup, Choose *By Material*

You can parent it later to the model.

In *Object Mode*

- Select the mesh
- Select the Armature
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> With automatic weights

[image]

Note: When exporting from *MakeHuman* you can also export with a rig (personally I prefer the MHX rig because it doesn't pollute the outliner with all these WGT* objects)

Related: 
[What are the not so obvious features of Rigify?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1530/what-are-the-not-so-obvious-features-of-rigify)