# I can't move the finger from makehuman model with rigs

Tags: modeling, makehuman

I have selected the finger that I want to move. I clicking in Transformation manipulators:Rotate and Gimbal.[image]

When I press "R" to move it. Nothing happens.
The green colour from the finger selected is moving but the finger doesn't
[image]

When I try to move the arm. The rigs are moving but not the arm.
[image]
Thank you so much

The file is this
[image]

Comment: Can you upload your file?

Comment: I attach the file to the original message. Thanks

Comment: Sorry but i can't see it

Comment: you can use this one for upload your files 
http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I attached it in the original message. Thanks

Comment: You upload a picture, not the file blend ;) we need the file so i can open it and check the problem

Comment: Please can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: I can't upload the file on blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: Sure use this link and follow the steps 
http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/help/

Comment: You can use dropbox i think its simplier

Comment: Thank you for all the information.  the post is  [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1073" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1073/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36403/discussion-between-meri-and-fuboski).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a rigify rig the fingers curl is controled by scaling <kbd>S</kbd>. This automaticaly rotates all finger bones at once.

Related: [What are the not so obvious features of Rigify?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1530/what-are-the-not-so-obvious-features-of-rigify)

Comment: I did that but the finger don't move.

Comment: I tried it with other part of the body but I can't move anything. I used use preference/add ons/ rigs  but nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you first:

don't use this setting, that could be confusing sometimes when you have to choose a control.

[image]

Use this one

[image]

then the rig should be like that:

[image]

If i want to move it no problem it works!!

[image]

and works still with fingers pressing <kbd>G</kbd> or <kbd>R</kbd>

[image]

If i want to move a finger i right click on control near the finger; this one it will change color (light blue) then <kbd>G</kbd> or <kbd>R</kbd> (let's use <kbd>R</kbd> in our example) and we'll have this situation

[image]

move now the mouse and the mesh will deform like you want; for example

[image]

Now the point is: i can't understand why this should not work for you. 
Please check all these thing

1) in the addons rigify musst be ON
[image]

2) in User preferences/File you have to check this ON
[image]

**PS: after check all, remember to Save User preferences than quit blender and restart it.**